# Context Free Grammar for language

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-free

The language is $L = \{a^{i} b^{j} c^{k} \;|\; k \neq 2j\}$. I'm trying to write a grammar for this language, what I have so far is:

$S \rightarrow AT_{1} \;|\; AT_{2} \;|\; AT_{3} \;|\; AB \;|\; AC$

$A \rightarrow aA \;|\; \varepsilon$

$B \rightarrow bB \;|\; \varepsilon$

$C \rightarrow cC \;|\; \varepsilon$

$T_{1} \rightarrow bbB'T_{1}c \;|\; \varepsilon $   (for $2j > k$)(1)

$B' \rightarrow bB' \;|\; b$

$T_{2} \rightarrow bT_{2}ccC'\;|\; \varepsilon$ (for $2j < k$)

$C' \rightarrow cC' \;|\; c$

$T_{3} \rightarrow bT_{3}c \;|\; \varepsilon$ (for $j = k$)

the problem that I am having is, the string $bbccc$  can't be generated although valid, in that case $j = 2$ and $k = 3$  so $2\times 2 > 3$  corresponding to production rule (1), how can I fix this?

Comment: Your grammar has several other problems. For example, $T_1$ doesn't produce any string of non-terminals, and $a^i$ is produced by your grammar. Also, what is case 3 for?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus just fixed it, can you propose a solution ? case 3 is for when b's equal c's, which is accepted.

Comment: Hint: can you think of **two** grammars? One for $L_> = \{a^{i} b^{j} c^{k} \;|\; k  > 2j\}$, and the other for $L_< = \{a^{i} b^{j} c^{k} \;|\; k < 2j\}$? Divide and conquer. Think of each problem at a time and don't try to combine them at the beginning

Comment: Another hint: $a^i$ is clearly not the difficulty here. Leave it out for the time being.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Production for $\{b^jc^k\; |\; j\neq 2k \}$ can be written as

$B\rightarrow bBcc\;|\;bB_1\;|\;cB_2$

$B_1\rightarrow bB_1\;|\;b\;|\;c\;|\;\epsilon$

$B_2\rightarrow cB_2\;|\;c\;|\;\epsilon$

You can see that it can't accept $bbcccc$. We can use $B\rightarrow bBcc$ twice but the final $B$ would have to be substituted with either `b` or `c`.

It accepts $bbccc$ as $B\rightarrow (bBcc) \rightarrow b(bB_1)cc \rightarrow bb(c)cc$

For even number of `c`s $B\rightarrow bBcc$ can be used. For odd number of `c`s, an extra $B_1\rightarrow c$ can be used.

So $\{a^ib^jc^k\; |\; j\neq 2k \}$ has the following grammar

$S\rightarrow AB$

$A\rightarrow aA \;|\; \epsilon$

$B\rightarrow bBcc\;|\;bB_1\;|\;cB_2$

$B_1\rightarrow bB_1\;|\;b\;|\;c\;|\;\epsilon$

$B_2\rightarrow cB_2\;|\;c\;|\;\epsilon$

**Note:** `i` can be `0` but `j` and `k` can not be `0` simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of a grammar for $\{a^ib^jc^k \mid k\neq 2j \}$. It is based on the very straight-forward grammar for $\{a^ib^jc^k \mid k= 2j \}$, but then it requires to have either an additional (non-empty) sequence of `b`s or an additional (non-empty) sequence of `c`s to show up in the proper place. There is on special rule that produces $a^*bc$.

$S\rightarrow AbBE \mid AECc \mid Abc$

$A\rightarrow aA \mid \varepsilon$

$B\rightarrow bB \mid \varepsilon$

$C\rightarrow cC \mid \varepsilon$

$E\rightarrow bEcc\mid \varepsilon$