# Is the language $L = \{0^i 1^j | i \ne 2j\}$ context free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I have been trying to find a a CFG for this language generated.

I came to the conclusion that I need three parts

1. When $i \le j$
2. When $j < 2j < i$
3. When $j < i < 2j$

I was able to come up the production rules for 1 and 2 but I'm getting stuck at 3.

I thought I found a solution in [Context Free Grammar for $\{a^ib^j | i,j ≥ 0; i ≠ 2j\}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9804/context-free-grammar-for-aibj-i-j-%e2%89%a5-0-i-%e2%89%a0-2j), but when I tried for $0^81^5$ it didn't work.

I was however able to come up with a CSG.

Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Context Free Grammar for {a^ib^j | i,j ≥ 0; i ≠ 2j}](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9804/context-free-grammar-for-aibj-i-j-%e2%89%a5-0-i-%e2%89%a0-2j)

Comment: What evidence do you have that the linked answer doesn't generate $0^81^5$?

Comment: Specifically, in the grammar in [the accepted answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/9811/4416), the derivation is $S\to S_2, S_2\to Bb$ and then $B\to aaBb$ four times, and finally $B\to\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

I will only argue about 3), since this is the case you're having troubles with.

Consider $\{ 0^i 1^j \mid j \le i \le 2j \}$ for a moment.
You can get a CFG for this language by noticing that you can "match" each occurrence of a $1$ to either $1$ or $2$ occurrences of $0$s (in such a way that every occurrence of $0$ is matched exactly to a single occurrence of $1$).

$$
S \to 0S1 \mid 00S1 \mid \varepsilon
$$

To get a CFG for $\{ 0^i 1^j \mid j < i < 2j \}$ you just need to ensure that a) there is at least one $1$ matched to a single $0$, and b) there is at least one $1$ matched to two $0$s.

Since using the order of the rules is irrelevant and using $S \to 0S1$ followed $S \to S \to 00S1$  generates $3$ zeros and $2$ ones, we can  simulate the execution of these rules as the last step each possible derivation by replacing $S \to \varepsilon$ with $S \to 00011$. To summarize, the final grammar is:
$$
S \to 0S1 \mid 00S1 \mid 00011.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You only need a grammar for i < 2j and i > 2j. Have a symbol X that gets converted to 0, 01, 0X, 0X1 or 0X11, so j < 2i. And a symbol Y that gets converted to 1 or 0Y11Z, with Z converted to eps or Z1, so j > 2i.

```
S -> X | Y
X -> 0 | 01 | 0X | 0X1 | 0x11
Y -> 1 | 0Y11Z
Z -> eps | Z1
```